# Sublime Text 2 Python.sublime-package

Tags: python, package, sublimetext

I tried adding some extra features to my python package in Sublime Text 2 and it ended up showing: Error trying to parse settings . **Unexpected trailing characters in ... {my path} \User\Python.sublime-package:1:11**

I searched the internet for about 3 hours and my frustration grown off the charts.

My ideea was trying to find the default code for the python package but it didn`t work out. Also , uninstalled and installed python and sublime for like 20 times , still not working.
Please help me

Comment: Sounds like you have an error in the JSON-format settings file. Can you post that here please?

Comment: http://ge.tt/1y3q4Wj/v/0?c // hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Remove existing */User/Python.sublime-package* and try manually unzip *Python.sublime-package* (change it's extension to *.zip*) to Package folder /Packages/Python. Package folder can be revealed via `Preferences->Browse Packages...` command.